# jQuery mobile no click events after .load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, hyperlink, load

if I load a page into "curr_recipe" and want to go back with the link in the footer to #home no click events are available anymore on the page #home; the jquery code comes from m-index.php and i'm using the user agent function, because I want this page on mobile devices and pc's/laptops etc.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSearch").click(function() {searchFiles()});
        $("#testrecipe").click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage("#actRecipe");
            $("#curr_recipe").load("htmltodisplay.html", function() {
                $.mobile.changePage("#home", {transition: "fade"});
            });
        });
        $("#btnReset").click(function() {resetInput()});
        $("#txtRecipe").click(function() {resetInput()});           
        $("#toSearch").click(function() {$.mobile.changePage("#searchPage", {transition: "slide"})});
        $("#allrecipes").click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage("#recipePage", {transition: "slide"});
            readFiles(true);
        });
});

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Head</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>What to do?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul style="font-size:24px;" data-role="listview">
                <button id="toSearch">Rezept suchen</button>
                <button id="allrecipes">Alle Rezepte</button>
                <button id="testrecipe">Test Rezept</button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="actRecipe">
    <div id="curr_recipe" data-role="content"> 

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="oneFooter">
         <a style="font-size: 24px; width: 100%; border-radius: 0px;" href="#home" data-transition="fade">Menü</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**the page to load**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="./jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen" href="./css/recipe_screen.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<title></title>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

        if (UserAgent.search(/(iphone|ipod|opera mini|fennec|palm|blackberry|android|symbian|series60)/) > -1) {
            // mobiles Endgerät
            document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";
        } else {}

    });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="title"></div>
<h2 class="rphone"></h2>
<div class="content">
    <ul id="ingredients">

    </ul>
</div>
<h2 class="rphone"> </h2>
<div class="content" id="cooking">

</div>
<div id="back">
    <a id="linkback" href="/rezepteV1/index.php">Zum Menü</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to add a callback to your load()
Actually a callback is executed only when load() is done

Comment: Make sure you have no errors in your .html file loaded. I.e. tags not closed or click event inside that file.

Comment: there are no errors in the .html file and I added an callback:
   $("#testrecipe").click(function() {
      $.mobile.changePage("#actRecipe");
      $("#curr_recipe").load("anypage.html", function() {
       $.mobile.changePage("#home", {transition: "fade"});
      });
   });

but there's still the same problem, I can see the page #home, but I can't "interact" until i reload the page manually

Comment: Can you post your page structure? Maybe you have duplicate id?

Comment: i posted my structure, but do you want to see the rest of my pages too?

Comment: Just remove `.ready`, don't use it with jquery mobile

Comment: I did but now I get errors because of changing innerHTML of elements which doesn't exist

Comment: If you get such an error, then the elements aren't loaded into DOM. I'll give you an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but what is jsfiddle? ):

Comment: @tommygeek http://jsfiddle.net/ a place where people can put code online with minimal effort so we can reproduce error and find solution

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Mkrbr/ menu button is working normally without `.ready()`. What versions of jQm and jQuery are you using?

Comment: I created an account on jsfiddle and now? oh god, i feel so stupid right now

Comment: jQm: 1.3.1
jQuery: 1.8.2

Comment: it's recommended to use jQuery 1.9.1, have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: @tommygeek create a jsfiddle for it ;) i copy/paste your question in the chatroom, it will give you more visibility

Comment: @tommygeek you should have enough rep to ask your question in the chatroom now; here you go: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-a-room-with-a-view-and-a-model-and-a-controller

Comment: thank you happy ninja and omar!
@Omar yes i checked the fiddle, but I don't know what's the difference of your version

Comment: if you want, send me your files by email.

Comment: do you want the whole project? with the pc version too?

Comment: only the files where you're encountering this problem. omarmt [at] gmail . com

Comment: do you want a dropbox link or an archive?

Comment: ok dropbox will do the job :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30658/discussion-between-omar-and-tommygeek)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

have you check jquery on()? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Let suppose the event cannot be fired because the element doesn't exist at the time. Using on() you could wait for it so it could be fired at any moment no matter what.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand how to /:

Comment: can you provide more code? maybe the problem is not where you think it is

Comment: you mean I should replace the button click events on the #home page with jquery on() ?

Comment: sorry, this is my first project with jquery! ok, I'll try it

Comment: you don't need to feel sorry ;)

Comment: same error as before: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined_; if I go back to #home and hit btnSearch this error occurs